# Why does the for loop not work for the some iteration of range(N, N)?

Tags: for-loop, range, python-3.11

I have written a program using for loop but for some iteration the loop doesn't run

Below is the code I have written in python:

```
N = int(input())
for i in range(2, N + 1):
    print('This iteration works')
```

This is working as I wanted but my doubt is what is happening when the range is (1, 1) or (2, 2) or at (N, N)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range` function accepts up to three arguments: `start`, `stop`, `step`. When given just two arguments, Python assumes the first one is a `start` value, second one a `stop` value, and `step` defaults to `1`. You need to keep in mind that the stop value does not include itself, that is, the iteration stops at `n - 1`.

When the `start` value is equal to the `stop` value, it will return an empty `range` object. This is because iteration will stop at **the given number minus 1**. Taking your example range(2,2), the instruction in English is: **give me numbers up to 1 but start at 2**. This logically doesn't make sense but range function is polite so it doesn't complain. It just gives you back am empty object.

So, to answer your question, it doesn't run because it returns an empty object.